# How to access JobParameter which is fileName at itemReader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to validate fileName and the records. My application context is as below

```
<job id="job1" restartable="true"  >
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writter" processor="processor"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <validator ref="jobParameterValidator"></validator> 
</job>
```

My item reader context shown as below

```
<beans:bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
     <beans:property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['fileName']}" />
     <beans:property name="lineMapper" ref="testingLineMapper" />
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="testingLineMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper" scope="step">
           <beans:property name="lineTokenizer" ref="testingLineTokenizer" />
           <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <beans:bean class="testingFieldSetMapper" />
           </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
```

Java class shown as below

```
 @Component("itemReader")
@Scope(value = "step")
 public class TestingFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<VO>  {
private Resource resource;


public Resource getResource() {
    return resource;
}

@Value("#{jobParameters['resource']}")
public void setResource(Resource resource) {
    System.out.println("setR : ");
    this.resource = resource;
}
 }
```

I have use @Scope and @Component and @Value.. to get the "fileName". But i am hitting the follow errors : stack trace as shown below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.testingLineMapper' defined in class path resource [META-INF/contexts/integration/testing/batch-job-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '.....TestingFieldSetMapper#78ef78ef' of type [.....TestingFieldSetMapper] while setting bean property 'fieldSetMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '.....TestingFieldSetMapper#78ef78ef': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void .....TestingFieldSetMapper.setResource(javax.annotation.Resource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33) ~[spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:653) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:604) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2eaf1723.mapLine(<generated>) ~[cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:188) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:685) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a26d24dc.doRead(<generated>) [cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:148) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:371) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) [spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:262) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:248) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48) [spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114) [spring-batch-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:151) [spring-batch-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at .....TestJob.testJobParameter(TestJob.java:88) [bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at ........test.support.jpa.JpaUnit$1.evaluate(JpaUnit.java:136) [bin/:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '.....TestingFieldSetMapper#78ef78ef': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void .....TestingFieldSetMapper.setResource(javax.annotation.Resource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void .....TestingFieldSetMapper.setResource(javax.annotation.Resource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:141) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:715) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 93 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:207) ~[spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:71) ~[spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:52) ~[spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93) ~[spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:138) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
```

Can someone tell me whats going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace?  Off the top of my head, I'd remove the annotations and just configure it in XML since you are already using XML based configuration.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I have modified the question by add full stack trace, add the getter and setter for fileName and added scope="step" beside defaultLineMapper. Actually I want to get fileName from Java to validate with file's records. Beside using annotation, what else the method can use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd configure this.  Remove the annotations from your `FieldSetMapper`.  Since you are already using XML based configuration, configure this there.  Then update the configuration as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="testingLineMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
          <beans:property name="lineTokenizer" ref="testingLineTokenizer" />
          <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="testingFieldSetMapper"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="testingFieldSetMapper" class="TestingFieldSetMapper" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['fileName']}" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Actually what i need is to access jobParameters which is property name="resource"(fileName) at Java side. I still unable to get JobParameters(fileName) at itemReader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get what you are doing. Thanks.